# How can I install Ubuntu on a new device that I made myself?

Tags: boot, networking, server

For example, I have a device that I made myself with chipsets and a new design.

You can think it is like a tablet, but it is not, because I am doing other things with this device.

I need to install Ubuntu on it, but I'm not sure how to  install an OS on a new device or chipset.

I know that in robotics, we can upload the software on the chipset via C programming. But for my device, I am unsure how to go about this... I didn't design the device, and I'm asking this question to know how i have to build my way?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect people will need more information about your device and how you load other information on it.

First thing I suggest you do is identify whether your device meets system requirements for Ubuntu see for example  [Installation/SystemRequirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

You presumably have already discovered Ubuntu may be insrtalled on devices other than conventional PCs see for example [RaspberryPi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi)